# Toolchain build python3 kivy error - Kivy ios ,bash

Tags: python, ios, python-3.x, kivy, toolchain

The Command which  I ran:

```
toolchain build python3 kivy
```

And the error is(output) :

```
Exception in thread background thread for pid 30326:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1633, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2557, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2261, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 861, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_77: 

  RAN: /Users/macbook/Desktop/Button/build/hostpython3/x86_64/Python-3.8.2/configure --prefix=/Users/macbook/Desktop/Button/dist/hostpython3 --with-openssl=/Users/macbook/Desktop/Button/dist/hostopenssl

  STDOUT:
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
checking for python3.8... python3.8
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "darwin"
checking for gcc... clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics accepts -g... yes
checking for clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics opt... (17382 more, please see e.stdout)

  STDERR:


[INFO    ] cd /Users/macbook/Desktop/Button/build/hostpython3/x86_64/Python-3.8.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/toolchain", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1497, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1270, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.command)()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1323, in build
    build_recipes(args.recipe, ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1121, in build_recipes
    recipe.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 700, in execute
    self.build_all()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 85, in _cache_execution
    f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 794, in build_all
    self.build(arch)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 85, in _cache_execution
    f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 781, in build
    self.build_arch(arch)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 833, in build_arch
    getattr(self, build)()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy_ios/recipes/hostpython3/__init__.py", line 70, in build_x86_64
    _env=build_env)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 67, in shprint
    for line in cmd:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 907, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 837, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 861, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_77: 

  RAN: /Users/macbook/Desktop/Button/build/hostpython3/x86_64/Python-3.8.2/configure --prefix=/Users/macbook/Desktop/Button/dist/hostpython3 --with-openssl=/Users/macbook/Desktop/Button/dist/hostopenssl

  STDOUT:
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
checking for python3.8... python3.8
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "darwin"
checking for gcc... clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics accepts -g... yes
checking for clang -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics opt... (17382 more, please see e.stdout)

  STDERR:
```

I also tried also git clone **kivy-ios** but it gave same error.

If you will say build **python2** ,it's not working.

I'm waiting for answers.

For Stack overflow controls i will copy-paste

I also tried also git clone kivy-ios but it gave same error.

If you will say build python2 ,it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : update `Xcode` and update `Mac os`.